# Xamarin : How to set string substring clickable?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, hashtag

I have a problem to show my object field Description on Cross Platform Label . Description has many hashtag, that need to be clicked and open another page. Here is my example :

```
"I have some #issues that need to be #solved maybe Xamarin#Support can help me."
```

That is my description, and i want to put it on Label. How can i set those hashtag (#issues, #solved, #Support) to be clickable?

Comment: Are you using xamarin.forms?

Comment: Yes, i am. Xamarin.Forms.Label.

Comment: Can you please share solution?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a WebView and use simple HTML / CSS.  This would give you the most flexibility and in some cases is the simplest.

Another option would be to write custom renderers.  There are plenty of answers out there on how to do this natively but as a starting point.

- On Android you need to use a TextView with autoLink="web".
- On iOS, a UILabel should allow you to do this.

Comment: It's sound nice. Can i mix my content page xaml with webView? i just want to put WebView code for my label. So that i don't need to change all my code to webView code.

Comment: You can just put the contents of labels in `WebView` and rest of the stuff in other layouts and then put all of it in `ContentPage`

Comment: Ahh.. Its work!! But need to set the Width and Height of the webView. Thank's guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can change color, `ForegroundColor`, `FontAttributes` of the hashtags by using `Span` in the label. Sadly, `Span` doesn't have `GestureRecognizers`.

I suggest you to stack multiple labels and add `TapGestureRecognizer` on the label with hashtags.

Comment: I already consider about t it too. Using multiples labels can decrease performace, because i need to think about phone width, so that the label can go down, do get it what i mean?

Comment: Yes, this wont do any good if its a lot of text. You're gonna have to consider `WebView`